# Creating Login page with SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, insert

I am trying to create login page with sqlite with multiple columns but unable to insert values in it :
Here is my insertion query code:

```
    package com.example.doctorsmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DataBaseAdapter 
{
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "doctordb";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        static final String USERNAME_COLUMN = "UserName";
        static final String PASSWORD_COLUMN = "Password";
        static final String QUALIFICATION_COLUMN = "Qualification";
        static final String SPECIALIZATION_COLUMN = "Specialization";
        static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        static final String REGISTRATIONNUMBER_COLUMN = "RegistrationNumber";
        static final String CELLNUMBER_COLUMN = "CellNumber";
        // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                     "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD String,QUALIFICATION String,SPECIALIZATION text,REGISTRATIONNUMBER String,CELLNUMBER integer,MAIL String); ";
//        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
//            String makeTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOOD + "("
//                    + NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT," + CALORIE_COLUMN + " INTEGER,"
//                    + PROTEIN_COLUMN + " INTEGER" + ")";
        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;
        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        public  DataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public DataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }

        public void insertEntry(String userName,String password,String qualification,String specialization,String registrationNumber,String cellNumber,String mailId )
        {
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
            newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
            newValues.put("QUALIFICATION",qualification);
            newValues.put("SPECIALIZATION",specialization);
            newValues.put("REGISTRATIONNUMBER",registrationNumber);
            newValues.put("CONTACTNUMBER",cellNumber);
            newValues.put("EMAIL",mailId);

            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);

            System.out.println("USERNAME");  
            System.out.println("PASSWORD");  

         //   Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
        {
            //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
            String where="USERNAME=?";
            int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
        }    
        public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            cursor.close();
            return password;                
        }
        public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password,String qualification,String specialization,String registrationNumber,String cellNumber,String mailId)
        {
            // Define the updated row content.
            ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
            updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
            updatedValues.put("QUALIFICATION",qualification);
            updatedValues.put("SPECIALIZATION",specialization);
            updatedValues.put("REGISTRATIONNUMBER",registrationNumber);
            updatedValues.put("CONTACTNUMBER",cellNumber);
            updatedValues.put("EMAIL",mailId);

            String where="USERNAME = ?";
            db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
        }
```

}
And here is the code on the signup page when user press the `button` to create account:

```
 btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
    String qualification=editTextQualification.getText().toString();
    String specializaion=editTextSpecialization.getText().toString();
    String registrationNumber=editTextRegistrationNumber.getText().toString();
    String cellNumber=editTextCellNumber.getText().toString();
    String mailId=editTextMail.getText().toString();

    // check if any of the fields are vaccant
    if(userName.equals("")||password.equals(""))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }
    // check if both password matches
    if(!password.equals(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // Save the Data in Database
        DataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName,password,qualification,specializaion,registrationNumber,cellNumber,mailId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and here is the query for main login page for successful login:

```
   btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get The User name and Password
                    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                    // fetch the Password form database for respective user name
                    String storedPassword=DataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(userName);

                    // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                    if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }`enter code here`
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
//                    Intent intentlogin=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginSuccess.class);
//                    startActivity(intentlogin);
                    }
                });
```

This is my database helper class:

```
package com.example.doctorsmanager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
               super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    // to create a new one.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
    {
            _db.execSQL(DataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
    {
            // Log the version upgrade.
            Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

            // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
            // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
            // values.
            // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
            // Create a new one.
            onCreate(_db);
    }

}
```

This is log cat:

```
02-28 02:37:47.838: W/TaskDBAdapter(14302): Upgrading from version 1 to 2, which will destroy all old data
02-28 02:37:47.848: E/SQLiteLog(14302): (1) table LOGIN already exists
02-28 02:37:47.908: D/AndroidRuntime(14302): Shutting down VM
02-28 02:37:47.908: W/dalvikvm(14302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ab8ba8)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302): Process: com.example.doctorsmanager, PID: 14302
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.doctorsmanager/com.example.doctorsmanager.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table LOGIN already exists (code 1): , while compiling: create table LOGIN( ID integer primary key autoincrement,USERNAME  text,PASSWORD String,QUALIFICATION String,SPECIALIZATION text,REGISTRATIONNUMBER String,CELLNUMBER integer,MAIL String);
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table LOGIN already exists (code 1): , while compiling: create table LOGIN( ID integer primary key autoincrement,USERNAME  text,PASSWORD String,QUALIFICATION String,SPECIALIZATION text,REGISTRATIONNUMBER String,CELLNUMBER integer,MAIL String);
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at com.example.doctorsmanager.DataBaseHelper.onCreate(DataBaseHelper.java:20)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at com.example.doctorsmanager.DataBaseHelper.onUpgrade(DataBaseHelper.java:37)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at com.example.doctorsmanager.DataBaseAdapter.open(DataBaseAdapter.java:42)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at com.example.doctorsmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-28 02:37:48.048: E/AndroidRuntime(14302):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: As kodamirmo said, we need a look at how the table is created. Also, a logcat (i.e error message) would be helpful.

Comment: Post the query you are making to create tables.

Comment: Just add `_db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOGIN");` into `onUpgrade(....)` and try

Comment: I have posted the full database adapater class too... and @MD i want to ask where you wqant me to put this line.. Thanks for help

Comment: @user3187861 in `DataBaseHelper` and why you put `DATABASE_VERSION = 2` into your `DataBaseAdapter`? do you want to Upgrade it?

Comment: When I was trying with the version 1 the other coloumns apart from name and password were not been added to the table that is the reason i Upgraded the version

Comment: @MD i tried YOUR Suggestion but it is still not working. Please suggest something else

Comment: @user3187861 and Why you create `Login` table again becoz it's already exists. you just need to add some new column into it.

Comment: I am very new to android I just added the coloumns and version because my coloumns were not being added in to that. Now, I dont understand if I dont have to create the table again which line to delete and which to edit. That is why please tell me the solution with explanation as what to do what not to do thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the database multiple times. Move the database creation to SQLiteOpenHelper class and just create an instance of it in an activity you want to use it in.

Answer (score 0):

In this You have Made Mistake that You have altered the table column so that Database version you have changed 1 to 2.The thing you have to do is in SQLiteOpenHelper class file  in that use the code given below like that

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
{
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        _db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE login ADD COLUMN EMAIL varchar(16)");

        onCreate(_db);
}
```

In tha Alter Table Query the Email is the Column Newly added ,Use sqlite manager to make the database View

Answer (score 0):

//MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btlogin,btacc;
EditText emailid,passwd;
SQLiteDatabase db=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btacc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    emailid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    passwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    btacc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Signin.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    btlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String mail_id=emailid.getText().toString();
            String password=passwd.getText().toString();
            if(mail_id==null||mail_id==""||mail_id.length()<10)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct mail id.");
            }
            else if(password==null||password==""||password.length()<6)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct Password.");
            }
            else
            {       
                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from login where email_id='"+mail_id+"' and password='"+password+"'",null);  
                c.moveToFirst();
                if(c.getCount()>0)
                {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Show.class);
                i.putExtra("name",mail_id );
                startActivityForResult(i,500);

                db.close();
                finish();
                }
                else
                    show("Wrong Password or Email Id.");

            }

        }

        private void show(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
        }
```

}

//Signin.java class

```
public class Signin extends Activity {
EditText ename,eemail,emobile,enewpwd,erepwd;
Button bok;
SQLiteDatabase db=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin);
    ename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    eemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    emobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    enewpwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    erepwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    bok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists login(name varchar,email_id varchar,mobile_no varchar,password varchar,repassword varchar)");

    bok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name=ename.getText().toString();
            String email_id=eemail.getText().toString();
            String mobile_no=emobile.getText().toString();
            String password=enewpwd.getText().toString();
            String repassword=erepwd.getText().toString();
            if(name==null||name==""||name.length()<3)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct Name.");
            }
            else if(mobile_no==null||mobile_no==""||mobile_no.length()<10)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct mobile number.");
            }
            else if(email_id==null||email_id==""||email_id.length()<10)
            {
                show("Please Enter Correct Email id.");
            }
            else if(password==null||password==""||password.length()<6)
            {
                show("Please Enter Strong Password.");
            }
            else if(repassword==null||repassword=="")
            {
                show("password mismatch.");
            }
            else
            {
                db.execSQL("insert into login values('"+name+"','"+email_id+"','"+mobile_no+"','"+password+"','"+repassword+"')");
                                Intent in=new Intent(Signin.this,Show.class);
                                in.putExtra("name", email_id);
            startActivity(in);
            db.close();
            finish();
        }
    }

        private void show(String str) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}
//show.java class

```
public class Show extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
   String n = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String nn;
    String[] separated = n.split("@");
    nn=separated[0]; 
    //separated[1]; 
    t.setText(nn);


}
```

}