# Logout functionality in Android using a local sqlite database

Tags: android

How to make logout functionality in Android using a local sqlite database? I'm using a sqlite database to store data so that the user can use for logging in.

Comment: just flag it. flag to 1 if logged in and 0 for logged out. make it in table User maybe

Comment: Don't use local database for storing User's personal information. It will lead to security failure. Instead of, store User information into Shared Preferences and set the flag for login and logout as @Randyka suggested.

Comment: Use shared preferences for logging in and logout locally. Follow this link its a very good tutorial for maintaining user login session. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Logout:
               // SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Reg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
               // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              //  editor.commit();
                finish();
               // session.isUserLoggedIn()== false;
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);


                return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save one flag (i.e. boolean) in sqlite table. Whenever user start application check for the flag if it is set then user have already provided credentials for login otherwise ask user for login credentials.

Create another table where you can save user's signup data (login credentials). On each login check validity of credentials.

Note: You should encrypt user's credentials for security purpose.

See following links, they might help

[Creating Login page with SQLITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089648/creating-login-page-with-sqlite)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example